# How to build astrid task open source project

Tags: android, build

tried to build a open source project https://github.com/todoroo/astrid, getting error during import time only, as per the instruction imported facebook, api, greendroid, tasklist, tests will throw so many errors apart from those r.java errors. any idea how to build this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README.md file mentioned:

> import the astrid, astridApi, astrid-tests, facebook, and GreenDroid
>   projects

but I found that that didn't quite work.

What worked for me (as of 2013-05-23) was importing:

- android-aac-enc (aac-enc)
- actionbarsherlock/library (actionbarsherlock)
- astrid
- api (astridApi)
- facebook/facebook (FacebookSDK)
- greendroid/GreenDroid (GreenDroid)
- viewPagerIndicator/library (viewPagerIndicator)

FWIW, a hint to figuring this out was to import astrid first, then examine the bottom right portion of the Android section of the astrid project's properties dialog.